# Run superuser command from perl-CGI script via apache

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I do have a script where I can run native OS command (non-superuser command)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
system("ls -lrt");
```

and this works fine. System Command output is displayed on Web page..

However, I have my own binary "get_stats" (with super-user privileges) placed at /sbin directory. But web page appears blank, system command output is not displayed on the webpage.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
system("get_stats");
```

What are the changes required to be done in apache config or /etc/sudoers??

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Yes I have tried with "/sbin/get_stats" but it seems to be a permission issue that apache user cannot execute super-user commands

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/a/120209) looks similar to yours.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Bad luck for me ... Here is my code

    #!/usr/bin/perl
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    system("sudo -u root get_stats");

And /etc/sudoers have - 

    Cmnd_Alias      STATS = /sbin/get_stats
    apache          ALL=(ALL,!root,!#0) NOPASSWD: STATS